# Elegant way to JSON encode model containing list in MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is a question about something fundamental but I've searched far and I can't find a convincing answer. I want to JSON encode a whole model which includes a list of objects. The advice in every topic is to do @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model)). But I'm trying that and the list is being encoded as [Object, Object, Object]. Useless because I want the actual information inside these objects.

I know you can create a JSON manually and include each separate part of your Razor model. But this just seems daft because what is the point in the encoding shortcut in the first place if I have to explicitly create JSON objects for any vaguely or remotely complex model?

Surely there must be some common tool or technique that simply takes a Razor model and turns it into a JSON which includes the *complete* information of the model.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand you completely. Are you just tryign to get the string Json representation of the @Model from within the razor view?

Comment: Yes. @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model)) just stops at the top layer. Doesn't encode the actual contents of the model.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of what you are describing.

Comment: I think it's clear what I'm describing. If you don't know the answer then you don't know the answer.

Comment: Instead of encoding model in view could you just not return a JsonResult from your controller action?

Comment: But I've already rendered the view. I then want a Json of the complete model, not just the "top layer" of the model. I *could* make a separate Ajax call just to get the Json. Seems a bit silly though. There should be an easy way of doing it.

Comment: @JAbraham I wanted to make sure I understood the question. It is clear to you but still open to interpretation.

Comment: A list of items will be seen as a list of `Object` when you convert it to js object. You need to loop through the list and access properties of each item.

Comment: `Json.Encode()` does not stop at the _top level_!

Answer (score 1):

I created an extension helper method like this

```cs
public static IHtmlString Stringify(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, object model) {
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Serialize(model);
    var html = new HtmlString(json);
    return html;
}
```

and was able to call it in the view like this

```js
 var json = '@Html.Stringify(Model)';
```

While I used `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` You could as easily used Json.Net